# JavaScript how to copy a data like the ctr+c in windows

Tags: javascript

I have a button on my website.  This button is called `copy`.  When the user clicks it, I want to have something be copied.

I already make the JavaScript function like this:

```
function copyToClipboardCrossbrowser(s, el) {}
```

where `s` is the data to be copied.  How please?

Thanks

Comment: And what does `copyToClipboardCrossbrowser` look like?

Comment: @Charlie this is my question

Answer (score 1):

You can't with pure javascript, with Flash however you can work around it: https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard

Example:

**html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="copy-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" title="Click to copy me.">Copy to Clipboard</button>
    <script src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button") );

client.on( "ready", function( readyEvent ) {
  alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );

  client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {
    event.target.style.display = 'none';
    alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + event.data["text/plain"]);
  });
});
```

Comment: where is the copy function in your code please?

Comment: I went through that site. it seems good. but which files I have to copy and where should I copy them please? Thanks in advance.